# Photo manipulation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-photoshop-elements

I want to be able to create amazing photo manipulations however I don't seem to get enough ideas. How do you master the art of photo manipulation/matte painting?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  You master the art of photomanipulation by practice. For inspiration/ideas you can look at the work of others. Behance is pretty good for finding excellent examples, DeviantArt is another good site.

Answer (score 3):

A technically advanced flashy image is only skin deep if you have not an idea of the impression you want to create. Do not expect that combining things and applying effects randomly will bring out something arty. Of course a blind chicken can find a grain, but let's assume you can create something also without accidents.

Take a pen and a paper and start to draw something - no matter, how poor are your drawing skills, because this all is for you only. Write some explanations, too. The subject can be something familiar around you, but seen in a new context, something improbable, even impossible in everyday reality (see NOTE1) Avoid using the computer for anything until you have an idea on your paper. After you have the idea, you can start to make it real.

Trying to replicate something and working through tutorials are good ways to develop your skills, but practicing to invent something to say is more important.

NOTE1 An example of unreal: A nice lady rejects a young man. Both of them are books. The man is written by a popular pocketbook writer. The lady is a proud noble, written by Shakespeare.

Comment: What's a "hollow peel"?  Do you mean like "only skin deep"?  Peel doesn't mean that kind of skin in English - it's a false friend to Spanish "piel".  Peel is the skin of a fruit/vegetable, not an animal.

Comment: @BillyKerr OK. Is it now more understandable?

Comment: Not really. I've never heard of "a hollow skin" either. I think the expression you are looking for in English is "only skin deep".  It means "only the surface" or "superficial".

Comment: @BillyKerr How would you write understandably and shortly "an empty shell without any content under the surface"?

Comment: I'd say "it is only skin deep", or "it is only superficial". Hope that helps!!  Languages are complicated! ;)